# I can't exit my program when i show interstitial ads on my apps

Tags: android

I have create a video channel app on android. I can't exit my apps when exit alert dialog then show interstitial ads apps was close but in background the video was playing continuously please help me here is a screenshot

[image]

Comment: Don't post your code as a screenshot. It's of no use.

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

call `finish()` before `showInterstitial()`

Comment: i saw it exit in android 5.1 , but it doesnt work in 4.4.2

Comment: @PratikLamichhane what happened in 4.4.2

Comment: video is playing in background .and when i open my that  app video is playing in background .everytime when i exit my apps and re open everytime every video is playing in background i have to close apps by pressing home bottom then it shows my every app which are open when i clean my apps then the apps was exit

Comment: @PratikLamichhane did you stop the video before calling `finish()`

Comment: that was youtube video i am making my youtube channel apps